# Validation is not working properly- it appears that the field is required even when is inserted a value to the field

Tags: php, laravel

When the user click in "go to step 3" it appears with "                           `console.log(errorsHtml);`
" this:

```
<ul class="alert alert-danger mt-3"><li class="text-danger">The payment method field is required.</li></ul>
```

Even when the user selects a payment method it appears that validation error. Do you know what can be the issue?

Html:

```
 <form method="post" id="step2form" action="">
    <h6>Payment method</h6>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment_method" value="option1">
            <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
                <span class="mr-auto">Payment method 1</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment_method" value="option1">
            <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
                <span class="mr-auto">Payment method 2</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text-right">
    <button type="button" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
            class="btn btn-outline-primary prev-step">
        Go back to step 2
    </button>
        <input type="submit" href="#step2" id="goToStep3"
         class="btn btn-primary btn float-right next-step"
               value="Go to step 3"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Ajax:

```
$('#goToStep3').on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var custom_form = $("#" + page_form_id);

                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: '{{ route('products.storePaymentMethods', compact('id','slug') ) }}',
                    data: custom_form.serialize(),
                    datatype: 'json',
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    },
                    error: function (data) {

                        var errors = data.responseJSON;
                        var errorsHtml = '';
                        $.each(errors['errors'], function (index, value) {
                            errorsHtml += '<ul class="alert alert-danger mt-3"><li class="text-danger">' + value + '</li></ul>';
                            console.log(errorsHtml);
                        });

                        $('#response').show().html(errorsHtml);
                    }
                });
```

PaymentController method:

```
public function storePaymentMethods(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'payment_method' => 'required',
        ]);

        if($validator->passes())

        {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'success'
            ], 200);
        }
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        $errors =  json_decode($errors);

        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => $errors
        ], 422);
    }
```

Comment: How to show that in an ajax request? Like this is not showing "public function storePaymentMethods(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){ dd($request)...".

Comment: use chrome console network mode there you can check whether payment_method variable passing or not

Comment: In the network preview are just appearing the values introduced for the fields for the pervious step (step 1). The payment_method dont appears, just the fields of the previous step.

Comment: which version of laravel you are using

Comment: Its Laravel 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this and try

```
public function storePaymentMethods(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'payment_method' => 'required',
    ]);
    return response()->json([
       'success' => true,
       'message' => 'success'
      ], 200);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but stil appears "{message: "The given data was invalid.",…}
errors
:
{payment_method: ["The payment method field is required."]}
message
:
"The given data was invalid.""

Comment: did you check the payment_method spelling is  same in both side

Comment: Yes its equal in the PaymentController and payment.blade.php.

Comment: With that dont appears any validation error, it appears "Failed to load response data" when storePaymentMethods is selected in the network tab.

Comment: can you show images of error by update in your question

Comment: public function storePaymentMethods(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){
      dd($request->all());
    }

Comment: It shows "array:5 [
  "_token" => ""
  "buyer_name" => "John"
  "buyer_surname" => "Keane"
  "buyer_email" => "..."
  "name_invoice" => "re"
]".

Comment: This is only data from the previous step (step 1) the payment_method that is a field of the step 2 dont appears.